Some widgets don't appear in the main app
I'm trying to make an GUI to launch Ansible playbook, I've done a main app container with a menu to swicth between different frame.
The main.py looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk
import sys, os, subprocess, json
from Tkinter import Menu
import ttk
#import des classe frame
from classes_tkinter.launcher import *

#Application principale
class MainApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        #Titre de l'application
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.version = "1.0.0"
        self.title("Playbook Launcher v"+self.version)
        self.geometry("1200x950")
        
        #On fait le menu
        self.init_menu()

        #On paramètre les frames
        self.container = tk.Frame(self)
        self.container.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        #listes des frames
        self.frames = {}

        for f in (CopyScript,Reboot):
            name = f.__name__
            frame = f(parent=self.container, controller=self)
            self.frames[name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="nsew")
            
        self.show_frame("CopyScript")

    def init_menu(self):
        menubar = Menu(self)
        
        #Menu pour lancer des Playbook
        menu_playbook = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menu_playbook.add_command(label="Copier fichier",command=lambda: self.show_frame(page_name="CopyScript"))
        menu_playbook.add_command(label="Redémarrage",command=lambda: self.show_frame(page_name="Reboot"))
        
        #Menu pour faire des ajouts
        menu_ajout = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menu_ajout.add_command(label="Ajout playbook")
        menu_ajout.add_command(label="Ajout host")

        #Menu pour voir les informations stockées en base
        menu_consult = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
        menu_consult.add_command(label="Playbook")
        menu_consult.add_command(label="Inventory")

        #Ajout dans le menu
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Lanceur Playbook",menu=menu_playbook)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Ajouts",menu=menu_ajout)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="Consultation",menu=menu_consult)

        #Ajout dans l'application
        self.config(menu=menubar)

    def show_frame(self,page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().mainloop()

and for example one of the frames loaded looks like this, launcher.py:
import Tkinter as tk
import sys, os, subprocess, json
from database.database_helper import *
import ttk

class CopyScript(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.controller = controller
        #Titre de la frame
        self.label =  ttk.Label(self ,text="Copier fichier",font=("Arial", 14))
        self.label.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=550)

        #Widget pour les paramètres
        #choix de l'inventaire
        self.inventaire_labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(self,text="Inventaire")
        self.targetmachine_labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(self,text="Machines ciblée")
        environnement = []
        for r in Inventory().all_data:
            environnement.append(r[1])
        listbox = ttk.Combobox(self.inventaire_labelframe,values=environnement)
        listbox.pack()

        #pour la cible des machines
        
        self.inventaire_labelframe.grid(row=1,column=1 ,sticky='W') #,padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
        self.targetmachine_labelframe.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='W') # sticky='W',padx=10, pady=5, ipadx=10, ipady=5)

My problem is that self.inventaire_labelframe is well displayed but not the self.targetmachine_labelframe and I don't understand why.
I searched in the documentation but I haven't found a solution. Maybe there is an order in the grid?

It is because you have padx=550 on self.label.grid(...), so the second labelframe is pushed out of the viewable area of the window.  If you set padx to a smaller value, you can see the second labelframe.

Hum okay but if i dont put padx=550 , the label with text = "Copier Fichier" will not centered ?

You can try padx=(550,0) instead.  However using padx to center a label is not a good design.

:) I'll like to have a great method to center this widget without this :)

Well even after i remove padx , my second label frame doesnt appear in my app window :(

You need to put something into the second label frame. The size of the label frame without widget will be 0x0.

Hey hey i'm just a bit dumb ^^ the second labelframe does not appear cause there is no widgets inside ^^

thanks acw1668 ^^ i just found it without reading your answer :)
